# How do I make a background fill the whole screen in Libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx, image, transformation

I'm using this code to set a 800x420 image to be full screen:

```
public void show() {
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, h / w);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/splashatlas/splashatlas1.png"));
    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    TextureRegion region =
    new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 800, 420);
    sprite = new Sprite(region);
    sprite.setSize(0.9f,
            0.9f * sprite.getHeight() / sprite.getWidth() );
            sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth() / 2,
            sprite.getHeight() / 2);
            sprite.setPosition(-sprite.getWidth() / 2,
            -sprite.getHeight() / 2);
}


public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor( 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f );
    Gdx.gl.glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

But on real device it looks like this:

[image: On a real device]

I tried to `setSize` with different parameters:

```
    sprite.setSize(1.0f,
            1.0f  );
```

Now it's fullscreen, but it's really stretched:

[image: fullscreen, but stretched]

What is the way to set a background to be full screen? I want it to look like this:

[image: what I want]

Comment: change `new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 800, 420);` to `new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, w, h);`

Comment: this gives me a white screen.

Comment: this zoom the picture too much ... its looks blue now

Comment: i updated the question ..

Comment: ah ok, I had a chance to look at the documentation. try `sprite.setSize(1.0f, 1.0f);`

Comment: I've already tried that , check the question again :)

Comment: You can add your own solution as an answer and accept it! That makes it easier for future readers with the same problem to find it.

Comment: i know , but because i am new here i was not allowed until now to post my answer . and i now i have to wait 21 hours to accept my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem was in my images size , i set the viewport to be 800x480 but the images size was 800x420 , i just changed the image size to 800x480 and in setSize() i changed it like the following :

```
sprite.setSize(1f,
            1f * sprite.getHeight() / sprite.getWidth() );
```

and its work perfectly now.

Comment: Consider using `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` and `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()` as that will set the sprite to the size of the device's screen, regardless of the PPI.

Comment: this will stretch the screen too much .

Comment: but anyway the method i used above should scale the splash screen according to the device width and height and regardless of the ppi

Answer (score 3):

In your `render()` method, you could set `Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);` which will set the background of your game to **Black**

Then you don't need to resize the sprite and the texture won't distort.

Hope this helped.

Comment: but this method will not give a good results if i decided to change my splash screen to colored sprite because it will be obvious that the splash in not full screen . but anyway thank you I've already solved my problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I wasn't aware that you would want to change the splash screen's color.

Answer (score 0):

In screen constructor I use `OrthographicCamera` and `Stage` with `StretchViewport`:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(800,420);
camera.setToOrtho(false,800,420);
stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(800,420, camera));
```

Then in render method of screen class I update the viewport:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width,height,false);
}
```

And it fits the screen perfectly. Then you just draw your picture in the render method with your width and height (800 and 420). So it should work. Also I suggest using constants for width and height.

Don't forget to use `super.render();` in your game class.